# FuelSDK-node posting multiple rows to data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, node.js

I'm trying to use the `fuelsdk-node` to post multiple rows to a data extension.  I know there is a REST API route to update multiple rows but want to use the SDK if I can.  Here is the code.

```
var deValues = [{
  "ProductID": "Testing4",
  "Name": "First Product Name",
  "ShortDescription": "This is a description of some product.  There could be multiple sentences"
},
{
  "ProductID": "Testing5",
  "Name": "First Product Name",
  "ShortDescription": "This is a description of some product.  There could be multiple sentences"
}];

var deOptions = {
  Name: "CommerceCloudTest1",
  props: deValues
};

var deRow = fuelClient.dataExtensionRow(deOptions);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Non-whitespace before first tag.
Line: 0
Column: 1
Char: B
```

Comment: I ran into the same problem and it looks like the API does not support import of multiple rows. Passing in a single row works